# Eclipse plugin development: how to add functionality to editor

Tags: plugins, eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin

I have been trying there last days to extend the default editor (java, xml, all of them) functionality,

what I want to do is add a big ruler with text on the side of every editor.

example:
a default editor page looks like this:

```
|-----------|
|source     |
|code       |
|           |
|-----------|
```

but i want it to be like this

```
|------|----|
|source|    |
|code  |line|
|      |text|
|------|----|
```

also i can't use a view because the text in my ruler corresponds to a certain line and has to scroll along with the source code.

I have tried to do this by implementing IEditorActionDelegate
since I don't want a new editor, but to add functionality, but I could not find any solutions.

---

Wanted to mention that for putting my solution in practice i extended AbstractContributedRulerColumn

```
public class MyRuler extends AbstractContributedRulerColumn {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.rulerColumns`. The component that displays the line numbers in text editors is added using this point, so it should be possible to add other information, too.

Example from the API doc:

```
<extension
  point="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.rulerColumns">
  <column
    id="org.eclipse.ui.editors.columns.linenumbers"
    name="Line Numbers"
    class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.LineNumberColumn"
    enabled="false"
    global="true"
    includeInMenu="false">
    <placement
       gravity="0.9">
       <after id="org.eclipse.ui.editors.columns.annotations"/>
    </placement>
    <targetClass
       class="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor">
    </targetClass>
  </column>
</extension>
```

Comment: hmm, looks promising I'll try and see if I can add text to it.

Answer (score 5):

[Arne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231440/4794) gave some good suggestions, but it still took me a while to figure out how to write a plugin that adds a column of text next to the editor.

I [published a sample](https://github.com/donkirkby/live-py-plugin/tree/e94e16cb54dd1bc2bfc0b07b04230e83b34d204f) that just displays line numbers with an "x" after each line. Some useful resources I found along the way were:

- [Introduction to plugin development](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html)
- [Eclipse extensions and extension points](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/extension.htm)
- [LineNumberColumn](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.ui.editors/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/texteditor/LineNumberColumn.java.shtml) example that is really just a small amount of code that delegates to [LineNumberRulerColumn](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/equinox-incubator/org.eclipse.jface.text/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/LineNumberRulerColumn.java.shtml) buried in a bunch of compatibility stuff.

Comment: Waw, very nice, I'd love to give you 10 up votes for this, but I can only give you one :(

Comment: Awesome - I only can concure with Ha11owed, I was trying this so hard for a long time

Answer (score 0):

After working with the ruler columns extension point for a while, I learned about the `org.python.pydev.pydev_pyedit_listener` extension point that lets you intercept the PyEdit creation event and wrap other controls around it. Some digging in the [SWT widget reference](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/) let me add another pane on the right with a splitter, and I [published a sample project](https://github.com/donkirkby/side-py-side). The main advantages are that you can choose where the new display appears, you can use any controls you like, and the user can scroll if there's too much text to fit in the display.